# apex:outputtext automatically creates a table td element. How to prevent it?

Tags: outputtext

I have built an html table inside apex:pageBlockSection and trying to display a number field in currency format in one of the cell (i.e., in a table td). Since i need to format the number to currency format i have used apex:outputText with apex:param. But the output is not what i expected. apex:outputText automatically creates a td element and render the output. So, how could i prevent it from happening. Because the issue is it creates an additional td and the table messed up now. Any suggestions please. Is there any other workaround for this issue?

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr class="headerRow">
                <th class=" zen-deemphasize">Aging Periods</th>
                <th class=" zen-deemphasize">Invoice Count</th>
                <th class="CurrencyElement zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Amount</th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow even first">
                <td>0 to 30 Days</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">{!CustCreditInfo.InvLessThan30}</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,number,currency}">  
                        <apex:param value="{!CustCreditInfo.AmtLessThan30}" />  
                    </apex:outputText>              
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow even">
                <td>31 to 60 Days</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">{!CustCreditInfo.Inv31To60}</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">{!CustCreditInfo.Amt31To60}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow odd">
                <td>61 to 90 Days</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">{!CustCreditInfo.Inv61To90}</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">{!CustCreditInfo.Amt61To90}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow even">
                <td>91 to 120 Days</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">{!CustCreditInfo.Inv91To120}</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">{!CustCreditInfo.Amt91To120}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow odd last">
                <td>More than 120 Days</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  ">{!CustCreditInfo.InvGreaterThan121}</td>
                <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">{!CustCreditInfo.AmtGreaterThan121}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**Rendered HTML (from Inspect Element firefox)**

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr class="headerRow">
                        <th class=" zen-deemphasize">Aging Periods</th>
                        <th class=" zen-deemphasize">Invoice Count</th>
                        <th class="CurrencyElement zen-deemphasize" scope="col">Amount</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="dataRow even first">
                        <td>0 to 30 Days</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  ">0</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  "></td><td class="dataCol  first " colspan="2">$0.00</td></tr><tr><td class="dataCol  last " colspan="2">                 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="dataRow even">
                        <td>31 to 60 Days</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  ">1</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">20.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="dataRow odd">
                        <td>61 to 90 Days</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  ">0</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">0.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="dataRow even">
                        <td>91 to 120 Days</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  ">0</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">0.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="dataRow odd last">
                        <td>More than 120 Days</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  ">55</td>
                        <td class=" dataCell  CurrencyElement">54655.95</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

**Screen shot of the output:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is creating the  for you, you may able to try:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,currency}" styleClass="dataCell">  
    <apex:param value="{!CustCreditInfo.AmtLessThan30}" />  
</apex:outputText>
```

However, with that said, this isn't really an issue with [`<apex:outputText>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) but with [`<apex:pageBlockSection>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm). The formatting is coming from the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` because traditional `<apex:outputText>` just renders as a `<span>`. If you look at the documentation for `<apex:pageBlockSection>`:

> A section of data within an `<apex:pageBlock>` component, similar to a
>   section in a standard Salesforce page layout definition.
>
> An `<apex:pageBlockSection>` component consists of one or more
>   columns, each of which spans two cells: one for a field's label, and
>   one for its value. Each component found in the body of an
>   `<apex:pageBlockSection>` is placed into the next cell in a row until
>   the number of columns is reached. At that point, the next component
>   wraps to the next row and is placed in the first cell.
>
> To add a field from a Salesforce object to an ,
>   use an `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputField>` component. Each of
>   these components automatically displays with the field's associated
>   label. To add fields for variables or methods that are not based on
>   Salesforce object fields, or to customize the format of Salesforce
>   object field labels, use an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` component.
>   Each `<apex:inputField>`, `<apex:outputField>`, or
>   `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` component spans both cells of a single
>   column.

Notice how this specific tag is really only supposed to be used for a field. What is happening is that your `<apex:pageBlockSection>` is trying to format the `<apex:outputText>` like it is the only thing inside the tag. Unfortunately, that is what it expects. You may be able to do something by wrapping everything in an `<apex:outputText>` or something, but that kind of breaks what that tag is for as well. To be honest, your best bet is to get this code out of the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` if you can.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I have removed apex:pageBlockSection and it is working fine now. Now, i understand better how the container elements impacts other elements inside of it.